# strange exception when using $inject on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that needs to access a service. If I just simply add the service as a parameter to the constructor function of my controller it works just fine, but if I try to annotate the parameters with $inject so that I don't have problems later on minimizing the javascript I get the following exception:
"Cannot read property 'User' of undefined"

Everything still works OK but I don't understand where the exception is coming from.

The code for the Service is:

```
var myAppServices = angular.module('myApp.services', []);
myAppServices.factory('User', function(){
        var user = {
            name:"anonymous",
            id: -1,
            authorized:false
        };
        return user;
    });
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
function MainController($rootScope, $location, User){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, current, previous){
        console.log(User);
        if(User.authorized === false &&  current.templateUrl !== 'partials/partial1.html'){
            console.log("returning false")
            $location.path('/view1');
            return false;
        }
    });

}
MainController.$inject['$rootScope', '$location', 'User'];
```

The exception is thrown on the last line of code above where the $inject annotation is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `=`:

```
MainController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', 'User'];
```

Comment: Ups! I really need to get more sleep ;-)